# select special rows in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as below:

```r
 time        h    theta   Flux
    0.99   -28.8  0.2393 -3.12E-0
  0.9933  -28.81  0.2393 -3.12E-0
  0.9967  -28.83  0.2393 -3.12E-0
       1  -28.84  0.2392 -3.11E-0
  1.0043  -28.86  0.2392 -3.11E-0
    1.01  -28.88  0.2391 -3.09E-0
  1.0173  -28.92  0.2391 -3.03E-0
  1.0204  -28.94  0.2390 -3.01E-0
```

I want to select only the rows that the values of the time column equal to 1,2,3, etc.

Comment: Can you please make the data reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are trying to select rows where `time` is an integer. You can do that by

```
subset(df, time %% 1 == 0)

#  time     h theta  Flux
#4    1 -28.8 0.239 -3.11
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(0.99, 0.9933, 0.9967, 1, 1.0043, 1.01, 
1.0173, 1.0204), h = c(-28.8, -28.81, -28.83, -28.84, -28.86, 
-28.88, -28.92, -28.94), theta = c(0.2393, 0.2393, 0.2393, 0.2392, 
0.2392, 0.2391, 0.2391, 0.239), Flux = c(-3.12, -3.12, -3.12, 
-3.11, -3.11, -3.09, -3.03, -3.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go further than 3, replace `c(1,2,3)` by `1:round(max$time)` (for instance)

## Base R

```r
df[df$time %in% c(1,2,3), ]
```

## dplyr

You have several ways to do that

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(time %in% c(1,2,3))
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[time %in% c(1,2,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
subset(df, time == 1)
#  time      h  theta  Flux
#4    1 -28.84 0.2392 -3.11
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(0.99, 0.9933, 0.9967, 1, 1.0043, 1.01, 
1.0173, 1.0204), h = c(-28.8, -28.81, -28.83, -28.84, -28.86, 
-28.88, -28.92, -28.94), theta = c(0.2393, 0.2393, 0.2393, 0.2392, 
0.2392, 0.2391, 0.2391, 0.239), Flux = c(-3.12, -3.12, -3.12, 
-3.11, -3.11, -3.09, -3.03, -3.01)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```